# Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

I'm using 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I've set my LAMP stack many days ago. Today I upgraded my PHP version to 5.6. Trying to Debug my WordPress plugin using [php-cli](http://wp-cli.org/docs/plugin-unit-tests/) and my console prompted me the strange message:

> *Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.*

I tried all the possible solutions, like:

```
dpkg --list | grep php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and

```
mysqldump --lock-all-tables -u root -p --all-databases > dump.sql
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.6 mysql-client-core-5.6
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
mysql -u root -p < dump.sql
```

but nothing happened.

**Sources:** [1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/your-php-installation-appears-to-be-missing-the-mysql-extension-which-is-required-by-wordpress?answer=23398), [2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/upgrade-mysql-5-5-to-5-6-ubuntu-14-04?answer=22119), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22779915/1743124)

I tried `<?php phpinfo();`, it's displaying:

> **mysql**
>   Client API version    **5.5.50**

But command like:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.6 mysql-client-core-5.6
```

is displaying:

> *Reading package lists... Done
>
>   Building dependency tree
>
>   Reading state information... Done
>
>   mysql-client-5.6 is already the newest version.
>
>   mysql-client-core-5.6 is already the newest version.
>
>   mysql-client-core-5.6 set to manually installed.
>
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.*

How can I solve the warning and make my PHP do my desired job?

Comment: What do you get when you run: `php -r 'print_r(get_loaded_extensions());' | grep mysql` ?

Comment: @ScottDeagan I'm afraid, **nothing**.  Is that mean the MySQL extension is not installed. How come that is possible? And what are those messages, saying: _mysql-client-5.6 is already the newest version, bla bla_! :o

Comment: If you installed PHP from the repos, then `sudo apt install php5-mysql` should work.  Because the above isn't returning anything, it means your MySQL extensions are not being loaded. If you've built PHP from source, you'll have to build with `./configure --with-mysql` option. The only other thing I can think of is adding the following to your php.ini: `extension=pdo_mysql.so`, restarting apache, then viewing the output of `php -m | grep -i mysql` (to see if any MySQL modules are loaded).